# How could I evaluate this limit without using L’Hospital Rule

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\int_0^x\frac{\sin t}{xt}\,dt$$

Comment: Hint: try to use the mean value theorem for integration!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. It would be very helpful if you could use MathJax to type out your question instead of providing an image.

Comment: Please put some effort into asking your questions. This is not a site for people to do your homework.

Comment: Since $\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin t}{t}=1$, given $\varepsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that $\Big|\frac{\sin t}{t}-1\Big|<\varepsilon$ for all $|t|<\delta$. Then, for all $0<x<\delta$
$$\begin{align}
\Big|\frac{1}{x}\int^x_0\frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt -1\Big|&=\frac{1}{x}\Big|\int^x_t\Big(\frac{\sin t}{t}-1\Big)\,dt\Big|\leq
\frac{1}{x}\int^x_0\Big|\frac{\sin t}{t} -1\Big|\,dt<\varepsilon
\end{align}$$
That is $\lim_{x\rightarrow0+}\frac{1}{x}\int^x_0\frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt =1$. This is not surprising, at work is the first fundamental theorem of Calculus.

Comment: Thank you everyone! Sorry for the inconvenience. I will improve the way I ask in the next question. Thanks again!

Comment: Let $t=xy$.  Then, $\int_0^x \frac{\sin(t)}{xt}\,dt=\int_0^1 \frac{\sin(xy)}{xy}\,dy$.  The function $\frac{\sin(u)}{u}$ is analytic with a removeable discontinuity.  Moreover, for $y\in [0,1]$, $f(x,y)=\frac{\sin(xy)}{xy}$ converges uniformly to $1$ as $x\to 0$ for all $y\in [0,1]$.   Hence, we can interchange the limit and the integral to arrive at the coveted result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_0^x\frac{\sin(t)}{xt}\,dt=x\cdot\left(x^{-1}\frac{\sin(\xi)}{\xi}\right),\,\xi\in[0,x]=\frac{\sin(\xi)}{\xi}=\operatorname{sinc}(\xi)$$

By the mean value theorem.

By the squeeze theorem:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\operatorname{sinc}(\xi),0\le\xi\le x=\lim_{x\to0}\operatorname{sinc}(x)=1$$

Since the point $\xi$ is squeezed to zero by the limit on $x$. Sinc is a name for the function $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$.

Comment: Thank you very much. At first, I tried to use the improper integral but don’ know where to go next.

Comment: Please take a look at our post on [enforcement of quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards), regarding answers to low quality questions.